# docker compose with remote context gives ssh error connection refused

Tags: docker, ssh, docker-compose

I have a problem with docker-compose when I try to run this command from my local machine on my remote server using docker context:

```
docker-compose --context remote up -d
```

I get this:

```
ssh: connect to host xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx port 22: Connection refused
```

I only get this error with this command, everything else works fine (like ps or logs commands). Also regular ssh connection works fine, so I don't think there is something wrong with my ssh configuration.

Running the command with verbose gives no useful information, as far as I can see.

Comment: If you control the remote host, you can just run `sshd` in debug mode to see a verbose log of the connection and possibly figure out why the connection from `docker-compose` is being rejected.

Answer (score 9):

I had this exact issue. These 3 commands would run fine.

```
docker --context remote ps
docker --context remote run hello-world
ssh root@my-ubuntu-host
```

However, with more complicated docker-compose.yml files, I would get a connection refused error. Running with sudo did not fix the issue for me.

Turns out, ufw (which was pre-installed and pre-configured on my digital ocean droplet), was rate-limiting new SSH connections. And it seems docker-compose doesn't run everything in a single session, and instead runs each command separately.

The solution for me was to remove the rate-limit on SSH connections.

```
ufw delete limit 22/tcp
ufw reload
```

I'm about a year too late with this answer but hopefully it will help someone out there.

Answer (score 1):

For me, using sudo fixed the issue. I've no idea why, but it worked.

Answer (score -3):

Set environment variable `COMPOSE_PARAMIKO_SSH: 1` in your `.gitlab-ci.yml` and [read more here](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/8221#issuecomment-802875958).